# why people use Owin in signalr for maphub

Tags: asp.net, signalr, owin

i am not aware of `Owin usage`. so first please tell me briefly what is `Owin` and what is its usage and advantage?

now see the below code here one `startup class` is there

what does it mean `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRDemo.Startup))]   ?` namespace name is `MySignalRDemo  but OwinStartup pointing to SignalRDemo`....why??

when the function `Configuration()` will be called and who will called ?

```
using Microsoft.Owin;  
 using Owin;  

 [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRDemo.Startup))]  
 namespace MySignalRDemo  
 {  
     public class Startup  
     {  
         public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)  
        {  
           // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here  
           app.MapSignalR();  
        }  
    }  
 }

public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        }
}
```

see the two approach for `signalr maphub` but tell me why people choose first approach............what is advantage?

Answer (score 0):

Briefly Owin handles your applications authentication with the client, people use it because MS provides and it satisfies most requirements requarding authentication. If you want to know more or just so you can read at a high level what it does just read the API Microsoft provides. Its a bit of reading but it tills you everything you need to know in small pieces. [MSDN Owin.Security API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

To answer your second, third and fourth question about Startup; IIS uses this. At startup of your application IIS calls Startup, it only gets called once, bad things would happen if it gets called twice.

My general advice though would to read the documentation before you start using something you don't understand. If you don't really care just think of it as a black box, it works, don't look a gift horse in the mouth.